# WebRTC AEC on Android

Tags: java, android, c, webrtc, aec

I'm developing a **SIP softphone** app for **Android**, and facing the echo cancellation problem. I've  tried to solve it using **Speex** with no success. So my next shot is **WebRTC AEC** (Acoustic Echo Cancellation), but I cannot find any documentation about how to use it.

In my app, the audio is managed with AudioTrack and AudioRecord classes in Java, but the sockets that sends and receive are in a C code (integrated with JNI). WebRTC is a mega-project, and I only want to integrate the AEC module.

Does someone know which files I have to include, which flags does the compiler need, which function calls to do, and so on? I have the CSipSimple code, which also uses the WebRTC (but for other uses too) and I can't find out the easy and proper way to include and use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need the following files:

```
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_core_sse2.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_core.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_rdft_sse2.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_rdft.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_resampler.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/aec/echo_cancellation.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/utility/ring_buffer.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/utility/delay_estimator.c
aec/modules/audio_processing/utility/delay_estimator_wrapper.c
aec/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features.cc
aec/common_audio/signal_processing/randomization_functions.c
```

Usage:

```
void * aec = 0;
int status = WebRtcAecm_Create(&aec);
status = WebRtcAecm_Init(aec, 8000 /* sample rate */);

// Buffer the far end frames
int status = WebRtcAecm_BufferFarend(
    aec, play_frm, 160
);

// Cancel echo
status = WebRtcAecm_Process(
    aec, (WebRtc_Word16 *)buf, (WebRtc_Word16 *)buf,
    tmp_frm, 160,
    echo_tail / tail_factor
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but if you can't find what you need on [webrtc.org](http://webrtc.org), try the [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/discuss-webrtc) group.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Version of android referenced below is 4.1 (JellyBean)

The response is probably too late. However, for anyone interested in answers to **dbaustista**'s questions, consider following:

AEC is modeled by AudioEffect class. So, an AEC AudioEffect object needs to be added to the "effects-chain" of the RecordThread. I believe the implementation of AEC is built into the `libaudioprocessing` library. See additional notes below.

**Library**

```
/system/etc/audio_effects.conf
libraries {
...
   pre_processing {
     path /system/lib/soundfx/libaudiopreprocessing.so
   }
}
```

**Interface**

```
media/AudioEffect.h
```

**Example**

The example below shows you how to add an AudioEffect object to a **PlaybackThread**. Apply similar logic to the RecordThread i.e. Add the AEC object to the effects-chain of the RecordThread.

mediaframeworktest/functional/audio/MediaAudioEffectTest.java

```
      AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(
                                  AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                  44100,
                                  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                  AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                                  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                  AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),
                                  AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
      assertNotNull(msg + ": could not create AudioTrack", track);
      AudioEffect effect = new AudioEffect(AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_ENV_REVERB,
              AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_NULL,
              0,
              0);

      track.attachAuxEffect(effect.getId());
      track.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

**AEC Config Options**

TODO: add example configuration of AEC

Comment: I never got Speex Echo Cancellation working very well (lot's of noise). See my answer on how to include the AEC from WebRTC.

Comment: Thanks. Side note: SSE2 is for x86 architectures. If working on ARM based platform, you'd have to use aec"m" source files. Better still, you could link against the already integrated "libaudiopreprocessing"

Comment: i am using some thing like this 
AudioSource audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
localMS.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource)); 
i have created audiosource using Peerconnectionfactory and added that in mediastream track. So how can i use your code in that scenario ?